# Ignore controller or action in ReferrerUrl - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have some issue with `redirectReferrer()`.
When I **add a product** in **cart**, I do it with ajax (call : `http://wwwww.ww/quickview/product/add`).

Until here, everything is ok, but, if I want to remove product from my cart, the `deleteAction()` redirect me to `http://wwwww.ww/quickview/product/add` with the method

```
$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
```

Is it possible to ignore a whole Controller or just an Action in 
`_redirectReferer`, without any modification in the `deleteAction()??

I tried this `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setNoReferer(true);`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that is inside my controller (and action), that the referrer is setted

I return in JSON:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml')->toHtml();
```

I think this is this part who cause my issue..